# How to concatenate date in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following access database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Eol.png

I want to select data where date is between certain values as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Records where ???? <= #2022-10-22# AND ??? >= #2022-10-10#
```

How to concatenate (year & month & date & minutes) fields in SELECT query ?

Noting that Year1_1, Month1_1, Day1_1 and Minute1_1 fields type is short text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, use the `DateValue` function:

```
SELECT  * FROM Records
WHERE DateValue(Year1_1& "-" & Month1_1& "-" & Day1_1) >= DateValue("2020/1/1")
 AND  DateValue(Year1_1& "-" & Month1_1& "-" & Day1_1) <= DateValue("2030/1/1")
```